# How to use Telegram Text Markdown?

Tags: python-3.x, post, markdown

I'm trying to send a message with bold, italic or other markdowns with telegram api post methods, but its not working. Can you tell what I doing wrong in this code snippet.

```
CID = #chat_id
message_text = "Hello *World!*"                                #Trying to format "World!" in bold
requests.post(f"https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage?chat_id={CID}&text={message_text}")
```

when I post above request my bot is sending Hello *World!* not Hello **World!**    :(